# Python geocoder library: How to set proxy IP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-geocoder

I have using Python [geocoder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder) library for accessing coordinates. I could not find way to set proxy address for bulk accessing.

Comment: You said 'bulk accessing' in your question, can you explain it more clearly?
 ? You can set proxy address, but you can't do it for bulk accessing?

Answer (score 2):

From the [geocoder docs](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder/blob/e61175f2750f3c166e8d928ec6f47544e262d875/docs/examples/using%20proxies.md):

```
>>> import geocoder
>>> proxies = {'http':'http://108.165.33.12:3128'}
>>> g = geocoder.google('New York City', proxies=proxies)
>>> g.json
...
```

`geocoder` uses `requests`, so see here for more info:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies